# How to retrieve memory content from a process core file?

Tags: linux, memory, process, analysis, gcore

i want to analyse each memory block content produced by a particular process. So what i did was using "gcore pid" to get a core dump of the process, but i do not know how to retrieve the content out, can anyone help?

Comment: What does "analyze *each* memory block content" means? I am a bit confused by your usage of "each".... Why not just *some* of them? What kind of analysis do you really want to do. You should **edit your question** by giving a lot more motivation and context (in several additional paragrapshs). What is that process? Have you the source code of its program? What actual memory block analysis do you have in mind? **What is the real problem that you want to solve?**

Comment: In its present form, your question is unclear and too broad and confusing..... Please improve it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the good tool to analyze a `core` dump is the `gdb` debugger.

So you should compile all your code with the `-g` flag [passed to `gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) or `g++` or `clang` (to have [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information inside your [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable).

Then, you can analyze the (post-mortem or not) core dump of your program `myprog` with the command `gdb myprog core`. Learn how to [use `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Notice that `gdb` is scriptable and [extensible](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html) (in Python and Guile).

You could (but probably should not) analyze the `core`  file otherwise (without `gdb`). Then you need to understand its detailed format (and that could require months of work). See [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html).

BTW, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) could also be useful.

You could even use `gdb` to analyze a core dump from a program compiled without `-g` but that is much less useful.